# Flutter Navigation: push screen only if not already pushed, else just show that

Tags: flutter, dart

Right now, there are 3 static screen, and based on user's choice at first start, 5 to 15 dynamic screen. Dynamic means a single stateful widget, which receives a string value, and based on that value collects data from server.

Right now a modal shows all screens. From there user can click on any screen and Navigator.push(context) loads that specific screen. Problem with this method is, say user navigated from `A -> B -> C -> D`. And when in D, user presses B, then the stack becomes `A -> B -> C -> D -> B`. And B makes a new network request and collects new updated data.

But what I want is:

1. When pressing a screen, if screen is not opened, open that screen.
2. If that screen is already opened, then show that screen with its previous state intact.

So, navigation stack `A -> B -> C -> D` becomes `A -> C -> D -> B`, instead of `A -> B -> C -> D -> B`.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I also want this, but the answer below didn't work for me.

Comment: @RickyKresslein unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

[AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) can be used to preserve the `Widget` state:

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PageState createState() {
    return new PageState();
  }
}

class PageState extends State<Page> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin { // using the mixin
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // we have to call this method
    return Container(
        child: Text('test');
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; // we have to set this to true
}
```